# How to remove an array element with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an array element from some JSON using jq.
Below is the input and desired output.

```
jq .Array[0]
```

outputs the array element I want.

```
{
      "blah1": [
        "key1:val1"
      ],
      "foobar0": "barfoo0",
      "foobar1": "barfoo1"
    }
```

But how do I re-wrap this with:

```
{
  "blah0": "zeroblah",
  "Array": [
```

and

```
  ]
}
```

Input:

```
{
  "blah0": "zeroblah",
  "Array": [
    {
      "blah1": [
        "key1:val1"
      ],
      "foobar0": "barfoo0",
      "foobar1": "barfoo1"
    },
    {
      "blah2": [
        "key2:val2"
      ],
      "foobar2": "barfoo2",
      "foobar3": "barfoo3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "blah0": "zeroblah",
  "Array": [
    {
      "blah1": [
        "key1:val1"
      ],
      "foobar0": "barfoo0",
      "foobar1": "barfoo1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to delete just `Array[1]` or all elements of `Array` past the first, i.e., what should the output be if `Array` has more than two elements?

Comment: In this case there are only two array elements and I want to delete the second one. But more generically, I'm trying to understand how jq would allow for selective array element control. Maybe next time I want to delete array elements 1,3,5 and 11.

Answer (score 61):

Regarding the second part of [Paul Ericson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3158121/paul-ericson)'s question

> But more generically, I'm trying to understand how jq would allow for selective array element control. Maybe next time I want to delete array elements 1,3,5 and 11.

To delete elements 1,3,5 and 11 just use

```
del(
    .Array[1,3,5,11]
)
```

but in general you can use a more sophisticated filter as the argument to `del`.  For example, this filter removes the elements within `.Array` whose `.foobar2` key is `"barfoo2"`:

```
del(
    .Array[]
  | select(.foobar2 == "barfoo2")
)
```

producing in this example

```
{
  "blah0": "zeroblah",
  "Array": [
    {
      "blah1": [
        "key1:val1"
      ],
      "foobar0": "barfoo0",
      "foobar1": "barfoo1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering how to do the same inside a top-level array, the command will look like the following:
`del(.[] | select(.key == "value"))`

Answer (score 19):

In this particular case, the simplest would be:

```
del(.Array[1])
```

More generally, if you wanted to delete all items in the array except for the first:

```
.Array |= [.[0]]
```