# How to remove the last three elements of a list in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

This is how I do get all version tags of an image in a custom docker registry:

```
r=`curl -sS "$registry/v2/" \
    -o /dev/null \
    -w '%{http_code}:%header{www-authenticate}'`
http_code=`echo "$r" | cut -d: -f1`
curl_args=(-sS -H 'Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json')
curl_args+=(-u "$creds")
tags=`curl "${curl_args[@]}" "$registry/v2/$image/tags/list"  | jq -r .tags[] | sort -V`
```

The result could be something like:

```
1.0.0
1.1.2
1.2.0
1.2.1
1.0.1
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.2.1
```

Now I just want to get all tags except the newest three and if there are less than three tags, the result should be empty. So in this example I need to get

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.2
```

I tried to use `unset $tags[-3]`, but I think I do not get an array returned by the last curl call. So is `sort -V` working at all with this syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an array element with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876490/how-to-remove-an-array-element-with-jq)

Comment: `tags` is not an array, it's just a plain string variable (that happens to contain multiple lines, separated by newline characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` within jq, then index using `:` to get a range (negative indices count from the end).

```bash
jq -r '.tags | sort[:-3][]'
```

You can emulate version sorting by splitting the version string at the dots, and converting the items to numbers (works for the kind of version strings given in the sample).

```bash
jq -r '.tags | sort_by(./"." | map(tonumber))[:-3][]'
```

Output:

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.2
```

Comment: @user3142695 That's what `[:-3]` does.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU coreutils:

```bash
echo "$data" | sort -V | head -n -3
```

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.2
```

`-V` is "version sort"

`-n` with a negative argument is "print all but the last *NUM* lines"